# Unit test the code of an event handler

Tags: .net, unit-testing, ncover

How do I test the code of an event handler?

I have this

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(XmlException))]
    public void TheXMLValidationEventHandlerWorksOK()
    {
        string xSDFilePath = @"XML Test Files\wrongXSDFile.xsd";
        try
        {
            XmlSchema xmlSchema = XmlSchema.Read(new StreamReader(xSDFilePath), XMLValidationEventHandler);
        }
        catch (System.Xml.XmlException e)
        {
            Assert.IsNotNull(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private void XMLValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        throw e.Exception;
    }
```

But NCover states that the code of the event handlet itself is NOT tested ('thow e.Exception' is marked in red).

May I have to try to call directly to the event handler method? How do I create an instance of ValidationEventArgs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is couple of issues in the Test. For

```
 [ExpectedException(typeof(XmlException))]
```

Use [XmlSchemaException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 [ExpectedException(typeof(XmlSchemaException))]
```

In your test name provide exactly what you expecting. For example

```
 public void InvalidXmlSchema_EventHandlerExecutes_ThrowsXmlSchemaException()
```

You also don't need try{} catch{} blocks. The correct exception type would propagate and handled by the ExpectedException Attr.

Keep in mind that since you are the file system to read the wrongXSDFile.xsd this is not a Unit Test. This is an integration test. The test would throw an XmlSchemaException. Below is test would pass for invalid XSD.

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(XmlSchemaException))]
    public void InvalidXmlSchema_EventHandlerExecutes_ThrowsXmlSchemaException() {
        string xSDFilePath = @"XML Test Files\wrongXSDFile.xsd";
        XmlSchema.Read(new StreamReader(xSDFilePath), XMLValidationEventHandler);
    }

    private void XMLValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e){
        throw e.Exception;
    }
```

Comment: I'm now checking for all post I forgot to mark as an answer. Sorry for the delay